# Swagger Springfox for SpringMVC not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using springfox to automatically generate swagger json. Currently I'm using springframework 4.2.2. Here is simple stuff i've configed.

### gradle

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.3.0"
}
```

### SwaggerConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "my api",
                "description",
                "version",
                "terms of service",
                "contact",
                "API License",
                "API License URL"
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't see any api-docs in `localhost:8080/v2/api-docs`、`localhost:8080/{myapp}/v2/api-docs`, what am I doing wrong here?

### Edited:

Here is my web.xml and applicationContext.xml and rest-servlet.xml if needed.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>api</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lingxia.yueju"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="com.lingxia.yueju.spring.resolver.ParamArgumentResolver" />
            <bean class="com.lingxia.yueju.spring.resolver.NullableArgumentResolver" />
            <bean class="com.lingxia.yueju.spring.resolver.ValidArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.lingxia.yueju.spring.resolver.AllDomainExceptionResolver"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <bean class="com.lingxia.yueju.interceptor.IpBlackListInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you try adding `.pathMapping("/v1")` to the Docket configuration? Then try accessing the docs at `localhost:8080/v1/v2/api-docs`. The `v1` part comes from the servlet mapping you have specified